# how the data store into np.array format

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to store the data into np.array,by reading from line ,How can it do?

```
def convert_hdf5(lines,idx):
        num_lines = len(lines)
        if num_lines == 0:
                return
        with h5py.File("aa" + str(idx) + '.h5', 'w') as f:
                for i in range(num_lines):
                        line = lines[i]
                        fields = line.split(",")
                        x = np.array(fields[1:],np.float32)
                        y = np.array(fields[0], np.float32)
                f['label'] = x1
                f['data'] = y1
```

how can store x,y into a bigger x1,y1?

Comment: Use `h5py` if you want to work with HDF5 files in python

Comment: you have to define x1 and y1

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the input data `lines`.
Let's suppose that the input data are:

```
lines = ['1, 2, 3, 4', '5, 6, 7, 8']
```

to store this data as `int`:

```
for line in lines:
    fields = line.split(",")
    x.append(fields[1:])
    y.append(fields[0])
x_array = np.asarray(x, dtype=int)
y_array = np.asarray(y, dtype=int)
```